# creating Models with sqlite3 + datamapper + ruby

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite, relational-database, datamapper

How do you build a model with the following associations (i tried but couldn't get it to work):

**each Order has: a Customer, a SalesRep, many OrderLine that each has an item**.

I tried: when I do: Customer.all(Customer.orders.order_lines.item.sku.like => "%BLUE%")
the output is :[] 
instead of: '[#<"Customer @id=1 @name="Dan Kubb">]'

When I delete SalesRep: it works.

Customer
  has n, :orders
  has n, :items, :through => :order
SalesRep
  has n, :orders
  has n, :items, :through => :order
Order
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :technician
  has n, :order_lines
  has n, :items, :through => :order_line
OrderLine
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :item
Item
  has n, :order_lines

Comment: Do it pass DataMapper.finalize?

Answer (score 0):

Since the output isn't an error, it could be that you don't actually have the data in your database.

Try the following with `irb -r your_models_file.rb`:
- `c = Customer.create(:name => "Dan Kubb")`

- `o = Order.new(:customer => c) # Create and add technician unless it's :required => false`
- `i = Item.create(:sku => "BLUE") # Plus any other required fields`
- `ol = OrderLine.create(:order => o, :item => i)`
- `o.order_lines << ol; o.save`

That should create the records needed for this to work. Try this out, and if it doesn't work, post your entire models file so we can get a better idea of what's up.